# Java Quick Way to Create an Array with Set of Possibilities

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, osx-lion, set

What would be a quick and simple way to create a two-dimensional array with set of possibilities?

For example, if the number is 5, I want the array to be:

```
{{0,1},{0,2},{0,3},{0,4},{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{2,3},{2,4},{3,4}}
```

if the number is 6,

```
{{0,1},{0,2},{0,3},{0,4},{0,5},{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5},{2,3},{2,4},{2,5},{3,4},{3,5},{4,5}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
List<int[]> a = new ArrayList<int[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        a.add(new int[]{i, j});
    }
}
return (int[][])a.toArray(new int[0][0]);
```

Comment: Thanks. But how could I change this to a two-dimensional int array? a.toArray gives me an error saying that I cannot convert from Object[] to int[][].

Comment: Sorry, pass `new int[0][0]` to `toArray` and the result is castable to an `int[][]`.  Edited.